# How to clear google map existing polygons when a submit button is clicked

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to clear existing polygon on the google map and then auto a new polygon on google map when a submit button is clicked. My html code looks like this.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.9&
                                    libraries=drawing"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="draw_on_map.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
     <div id="map-canvas" class="gmap-con"></div>
     <input type="text" id="search_polygon" name="search_polygon" value="">
     <input type="submit" name="search_polygon" value="search_polygon" 
     onclick="getPolygon();">
     <script type="text/javascript">
          google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', draw_map_initialize);
     </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

my javascript file looks like this

```
function draw_map_initialize() {
     var mapHeight = '400px';
    // Set default height to  Maps Containers
    $('#map-canvas').css('height', mapHeight);

    // Initialize map with markers(47.53187912201915, 7.705222390807307)
    mymap = new GMaps({
        div: '#map-canvas',
        lat: 47.53187912201915,
        lng: 7.705222390807307,
        zoom: 20,
        zoomControl: true,
        mapTypeId: 'satellite'

    });
    map = mymap
    drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
            drawingControlOptions: {

            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT,
            drawingModes: [
                google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
                google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON
            ]
        },
        //drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
        markerOptions: {
            draggable: true                   
        },

        polylineOptions: {
            editable: true
        },
        map: map
    });
  }


  function getPolygons(){
    var polygon_name = document.getElementById("search_polygon").value;
    $.ajax({
        url: url_prefix + "getPolygons",
        data: ({
            'polygon_name': polygon_name,
            'as_json': 1
        }),
        async: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            polygon_points = JSON.stringify(data);
            if (polygon_points.length === 2){
             alert('Sorry,No Area Stored with name '+polygon_name)                
            }
            else{
            var result = {};
            var count = 1;
            var path = [];
            for (var key in data) {
                obj = {
                    'name': key,
                    'coords': data[key]
                };
                result['area' + count++] = obj;
            }
      var polygon_coordinates = JSON.parse(polygon_points.replace(/u/g"").replace(/'/g, 
                                '"').replace(/\(/g, "[").replace(/\)/g, "]"));
            var polygon_start_latlng;
            for (var poly in polygon_coordinates) {
                for (var i = 0; i < polygon_coordinates[poly].length; i++) {
                    polygon_start_latlng = polygon_coordinates[poly][0]
                }
            }
            polygon_start_lat = polygon_start_latlng[0]
            polygon_start_lng = polygon_start_latlng[1]

            if (map === undefined) {
                draw_map_initialize();
            }
            map = sac_handler_map;
            map.setCenter(area_start_lat, area_start_lng);
            map.setZoom(30);
            var my_area;
            for (key in result) {

                my_area = map.drawPolygon({
                    paths: result[key].coords,
                    title: result[key].name,
                    draggable: true,
                    editable: true,
                    strokeColor: 'black',
                    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                    strokeWeight: 2,
                    fillColor: '#FF0000',
                    fillOpacity: 0.35
            });
            }
            }
        },
        error: function(data, status, e) {
             alert(e);
        }
    });
  }
```

What I done is, when a user types polygon name in the text box top search it and to display the google map. I can able to search the polygon and show it on th map. Now I want to know that how to clear the previously searched and shown polygon on the google map when a user types and search the new polygon. I tried Using my_area.setMap(null) but it's not working as expected.

Comment: You're specifying Maps API version 3.9, which has been retired for some time.  The current stable release is v3.17, which is what you're actually getting.  You could just specify v=3 to always get the current release. See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Versioning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare  my_area as a global variable i.e. add the following declaration at the beginning of the javascript file.

```
var my_area;
```

Also where are you writing the following method?

```
my_area.setMap(null)
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: @@ joyson: setting var my_area as global variable worked. Thanks